# In python, how do I print a table using double for loops?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my python code,

```
from fractions import gcd 
print "| 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15"
print "-----------------------------------"
xlist = range(2,16)
ylist = range(2,51)
for b in ylist:
     print b, " | "
     for a in xlist:
        print gcd(a,b)
```

I'm having trouble printing a table that will display on the top row 2-15 and on the left column the values 2-50. With a gcd table for each value from each row and each column.

Here is a sample of what I'm getting

| 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

---

2  |

2

1

2

Comment: Can you show us what you *are* getting?

Comment: @zondo View code+output [here](http://goo.gl/T3NYZq).

Comment: I just put a sample of the output, don't know how to display the entire output without having to edit it

Comment: Is there a print statement that will print the gcd values up to a desired number on an entire line without having to start on a new line?

Comment: Would `06 |  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15` as a sample line look about right?

Comment: to avoid printing a new line in python 2, you have to put a comma at the end, like this `print "hello world",` and the next print will be in the same line

Answer (score 2):

You can have it much more concise with list comprehension:

```
from fractions import gcd
print("   |   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15")
print("-----------------------------------------------")
xlist = range(2,16)
ylist = range(2,51)

print("\n".join(" ".join(["%2d | " % b] + [("%2d" % gcd(a, b)) for a in xlist]) for b in ylist))
```

Output:

```
   |   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
-----------------------------------------------
 2 |   2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1
 3 |   1  3  1  1  3  1  1  3  1  1  3  1  1  3
 4 |   2  1  4  1  2  1  4  1  2  1  4  1  2  1
 5 |   1  1  1  5  1  1  1  1  5  1  1  1  1  5
 6 |   2  3  2  1  6  1  2  3  2  1  6  1  2  3
 7 |   1  1  1  1  1  7  1  1  1  1  1  1  7  1
 8 |   2  1  4  1  2  1  8  1  2  1  4  1  2  1
 9 |   1  3  1  1  3  1  1  9  1  1  3  1  1  3
10 |   2  1  2  5  2  1  2  1 10  1  2  1  2  5
11 |   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 11  1  1  1  1
12 |   2  3  4  1  6  1  4  3  2  1 12  1  2  3
13 |   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 13  1  1
14 |   2  1  2  1  2  7  2  1  2  1  2  1 14  1
15 |   1  3  1  5  3  1  1  3  5  1  3  1  1 15
16 |   2  1  4  1  2  1  8  1  2  1  4  1  2  1
17 |   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
18 |   2  3  2  1  6  1  2  9  2  1  6  1  2  3
19 |   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
20 |   2  1  4  5  2  1  4  1 10  1  4  1  2  5
21 |   1  3  1  1  3  7  1  3  1  1  3  1  7  3
22 |   2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2 11  2  1  2  1
23 |   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
24 |   2  3  4  1  6  1  8  3  2  1 12  1  2  3
25 |   1  1  1  5  1  1  1  1  5  1  1  1  1  5
26 |   2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2 13  2  1
27 |   1  3  1  1  3  1  1  9  1  1  3  1  1  3
28 |   2  1  4  1  2  7  4  1  2  1  4  1 14  1
29 |   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
30 |   2  3  2  5  6  1  2  3 10  1  6  1  2 15
31 |   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
32 |   2  1  4  1  2  1  8  1  2  1  4  1  2  1
33 |   1  3  1  1  3  1  1  3  1 11  3  1  1  3
34 |   2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1
35 |   1  1  1  5  1  7  1  1  5  1  1  1  7  5
36 |   2  3  4  1  6  1  4  9  2  1 12  1  2  3
37 |   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
38 |   2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1
39 |   1  3  1  1  3  1  1  3  1  1  3 13  1  3
40 |   2  1  4  5  2  1  8  1 10  1  4  1  2  5
41 |   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
42 |   2  3  2  1  6  7  2  3  2  1  6  1 14  3
43 |   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
44 |   2  1  4  1  2  1  4  1  2 11  4  1  2  1
45 |   1  3  1  5  3  1  1  9  5  1  3  1  1 15
46 |   2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1
47 |   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
48 |   2  3  4  1  6  1  8  3  2  1 12  1  2  3
49 |   1  1  1  1  1  7  1  1  1  1  1  1  7  1
50 |   2  1  2  5  2  1  2  1 10  1  2  1  2  5
```

This works in Python2 *and* Python3.  If you want zeros at the beginning of each one-digit number, replace each occurence of `%2d` with `%02d`.  You probably shouldn't print the header like that, but do it more like this:

```
from fractions import gcd
xlist = range(2, 16)
ylist = range(2, 51)
string = "   | " + " ".join(("%2d" % x) for x in xlist)
print(string)
print("-" * len(string))

print("\n".join(" ".join(["%2d | " % b] + [("%2d" % gcd(a, b)) for a in xlist]) for b in ylist))
```

This way, even if you change `xlist` or `ylist`, the table will still look good.

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account the OP condition to print greatest common denominator

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out.  I am amazed that I have not yet been down-voted, but I fixed it so I shouldn't be now.

Comment: I removed my incorrect comment on format @zondo.  I think this works: "%2d %2d ..."

Comment: Ah, yes; it works beautifully.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the python print statement adds a newline by itself.

One solution to this is to build up your own string to output piece by piece and use only one print statement per line of the table, like such:

```
from fractions import gcd 
print "| 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15"
print "-----------------------------------"
xlist = range(2,16)
ylist = range(2,51)
for b in ylist:
     output=str(b)+" | " #For each number in ylist, make a new string with this number
     for a in xlist:
        output=output+str(gcd(a,b))+" " #Append to this for each number in xlist
     print output #Print the string you've built up
```

Example output, by the way:

```
| 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
-----------------------------------
2 | 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
3 | 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 3
4 | 2 1 4 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 4 1 2 1
5 | 1 1 1 5 1 1 1 1 5 1 1 1 1 5
6 | 2 3 2 1 6 1 2 3 2 1 6 1 2 3
7 | 1 1 1 1 1 7 1 1 1 1 1 1 7 1
8 | 2 1 4 1 2 1 8 1 2 1 4 1 2 1
9 | 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 9 1 1 3 1 1 3
```

Comment: I was never thinking of making a long string statement, makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what kind of character end the line using the end parameter in print.

```
from fractions import gcd 
print("| 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15")
print("-----------------------------------")
xlist = range(2,16)
ylist = range(2,51)
for b in ylist:
     print(b + " | ",end="")
     for a in xlist:
        print(gcd(a,b),end="")
     print("")#Newline
```

If you are using python 2.x, you need to add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top for this to work.